# Dynamically Select Machine Learning Models as Packet Filtering Algorithms within XDP

Tags: machine-learning, networking, kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am developing a simple tool integrating the machine learning model created with scikit-learn into XDP. I support decision trees, RandomForest, logistic regression, RidgeClassifier, and Neural Networks (MPC). One current problem is that the user should choose one algorithm before attaching the XDP program to the network interface. Is there a way to dynamically control the behavior of the XDP program connected to the network interface via some command lines or config files?

Link to Repo: [SkimXDP](https://github.com/Koukyosyumei/SkimXDP/)

The current implementation ask the user to select the trained classifier before attaching the program.

Specifically, the workloads of this tool (named `skX`) is as follows:

```
1. First, `skX` loads the pickle of a pair of pre-trained machine learning model and feature names from the specified file path. 
2. Second, `skX` generates C code for the packet filter, incorporating the loaded model.
3. Then, generated C code is saved to a file in the specified output directory, and helper headers are also saved.
4. Next, `skX` compiles the generated C code into a binary object suitable for packet filtering (default compiler is clang).
5. Finally, the compiled object is attached to the network interface, enabling packet filtering.
```

The example usage of this tool is as follows:

```
skX -m model/tree.pkl -d outputs -f skX_tree -i lo
```

In a nutshell, I would like to change the internal classifer **after** deploying the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with your already running eBPF program using maps, which you can access from user space. Red Hat does have a good [introduction](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/12/17/using-xdp-maps-rhel8#:%7E:text=Interacting%20with%20user%20space) to this (under "Interacting with user space" and "Some map caveats"), it also has the relevant code samples you should be able to just copy/paste.